# Querying Parquet file nested column scan whole column even when there's predicate pushdown applied to records

Tags: apache-spark, hive, nested, parquet, presto

I'm playing with parquet format.
I have parquet file of events, each consist of timestamp, topic, and tags.
the file is sorted by topic and then by timestamp.
I run query which can be described like:

```
select topic from T where topic = 404;
```

it runs much fast, and returns very few rows. It runs much faster than:

```
select topic from T;
```

When I change it to be something like:

```
select tags from T where topic = 404;
```

it runs as slow as running

```
select tags from T;
```

Analyzing the plan, it seems (when using spark), that the predicate push down is applied, but from the performance I can assume it doesn't apply to the column of tags.

I tested with hive, spark and presto.
Is there anything to do about it or any other technology that handles parquet nested arrays better?

- execution plan in spark:

> == Physical Plan ==
>
> *Project [tags#4]
>
> +- *Filter (isnotnull(topic#3L) && (topic#3L = 404))
>
> +- *FileScan parquet [topic#3L,tags#4] Batched: false, Format:
>   Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/example-path],
>   PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(topic),
>   EqualTo(topic,404)], ReadSchema: struct>

Thanks,
Roee

Comment: Please share the execution plan.

Comment: Hi, shared the execution plan of the query of "select tags from T where topic = 404".

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4502 addresses this

Answer (score 0):

It is a Spark issue documented in [SPARK-17636](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17636)

Comment: Thanks, but its not the same issue.
1. SPARK-17636 shows that nested field involved in the predicate, will not trigger push down. What I experience is that even when other fields trigger pushdown, nested fields are fully scanned.
2. This one is limited to spark, though the issue happened to me with spark/hive/presto. So if there's an issue is with parquet-mr itself.